# Stuck trying to write web3 RPC BalanceOf to get users metamask smartcontract token balance

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I've been trying to use the new JSON RPC methods https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#ethereum-json-rpc-methods to create a simple web page that can return the token balance of an ERC20 smart contract in metamask account.

I've only been able to successfully retrieve the balance of ethereum (with the following code)

```js
  try {
     balance = await ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_getBalance',
      params: [address,"latest"],
    })
    // covert to readable format (account for decimals)
     read = parseInt(balance) / 10**18; // will need change based on what token
    console.log( "Smart Contract Token Balance:" + read.toFixed(5) );

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Of course, the above returns the ethereum amount for the address.

For the life of me, I haven't been able to figure version of this using the new JSON-RPC methods and don't see any examples of calling a smart contract method like "balanceOf":

```js
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(theAbi, theTokenAddress);

  balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(theTokenAddress).call().then(console.log);
```

I've been stuck on this for weeks on/off as a side project and well, any pointers as I'm sure what I'm trying to do is basic - I just setup an account on StackOverflow for the first time to post.  Thank you

Also note, I'm linking this version of web3 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to get user account address from client side, and then retrieve balance of the account for whatever token you are interested in from server side.